# Aligning table entry (second column) vertically to first column

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

In the table I provided (picture) , some author names span two lines, which causes the corresponding formulas to not align in the middle. Ideally, when an author's name covers two lines, the formula next to it should be centered between those two lines. Adjusting the column type in the table should fix this alignment issue.But however the m{width} does not work.

My Latex code can be found here:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book} % Definiert die Dokumentenklasse
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Zum Umgang mit Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Zum Umgang mit Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{microtype} % Verbessert die Textdarstellung
\usepackage{enumitem} % Anpassbare Listen
\usepackage{graphicx} % Zum Einbinden von Grafiken
\usepackage{booktabs} % Für schönere Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx} % Erweiterte Tabellenfunktionen
\usepackage{multirow} % Mehrzeilige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{array} % Weitere Tabellenfunktionen
\usepackage{threeparttable} % Fußnoten innerhalb von Tabellen
\graphicspath{ {./images/} } % Pfad zu den Bilddateien
\usepackage{float} %Position von Bildern
\usepackage{amsmath} %Für Gleichungen und Verweis auf diese


\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=50mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry} % Seitenlayout
\linespread{1.5} % Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{helvet} % Helvetica Schriftart
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Setzt die Standardschriftart

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authoryear,sorting=nty,dashed=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {citetitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}


\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

%\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
%  \ifnameundef{author}
%    {\iflistundef{shorteditor}
%       {\printnames[editor]{editor}}
%       {\printnames[shorteditor]{editor}}%
%     \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
%     \printtext{(o.A.)}%
%     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
%    {\printnames{labelname}}%
%  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
%  \printtext{(}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}\printtext{)}%
%  \setunit{\printtext{}}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  }
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}
  
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}


\usepackage{csquotes} % Intelligente Anführungszeichen
\usepackage{subcaption} % Für Unter-Bildunterschriften
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Für Hyperlinks

\usepackage{acronym} % Für Abkürzungsverzeichnis

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Für benutzerdefinierte Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % Weitere Einstellungen für Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\setlength{\headsep}{0.6cm}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % Kapitelmarkierung
\let\originalchapter\chapter % Original-Kapitelbefehl
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar{\starchapter}{\originalchapter}} % Kapitelbefehl neu definieren
\newcommand{\starchapter}[1]{\originalchapter*{#1}\chaptermark{#1}} % Stern-Kapitelbefehl
\makeatother

% Ändert die Schriftgröße in Tabellen
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\small\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular\normalsize}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bf\huge}{\thechapter}{2pc}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Kostenfunktionen zur Approximierung der Pipelinekosten}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.16\textwidth} m{0.5\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth}}
\toprule
Autor & Formel & Kommentar \\
\midrule
Parker (\citeyear{Parker.2004}) & $(924,5d^2 + 12616d + 290068) * l $\tnote{1} & Dummy-Kommentar1 \\
Yang \& \newline Ogden (\citeyear{YANG.2007}) & $(1869d^2 + 300000) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar2 \\
\multirow{3}{=}{\textcite{Krieg.2012}} & $(1500000d^2 + 720000d + 213900) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar3a \\
& $(2200000d^2 + 860000d + 247500) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar3b \\
& $(4000000d^2 + 600000d + 329000) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar3c \\
ACER (\citeyear{AgencyoftheCooperationofEnergyRegulators.23.07.2015}), \newline ECN (\citeyear{Weeda.11.2017}) & $(1021,7d^2 - 20393d + 642720) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar4 \\
Johnson \& \newline Ogden (\citeyear{Johnson.2012}) & $(818,64d^2 + 14288,2d + 284530,3) * l$ & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
Andre et al. \newline (\citeyear{Andre.2013}) & $2306000d^2 + 762800d + 418869$ & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
Reuß et al. \newline (\citeyear{Reu.2019} & $292152 * d $ & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
\multirow{4}{=}{Elgowainy \& Reddi (\citeyear{AmgadElgowainyandKrishnaReddi.2022})} & $-9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241$ & Dummy-Kommentar5a \\
& $-51,393d^2 + 43523d + 16171$ & Dummy-Kommentar5b \\
& $303,13d^2 + 12908d + 123245$ & Dummy-Kommentar5c \\
&  $-9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241$ & Dummy-Kommentar5d \\
\multirow{3}{=}{d'Amore-Domenech et al. (\citeyear{dAmoreDomenech.2023})} & $1,4d^2 + 1,5d + 1,8$ & Dummy-Kommentar7a \\
& $-44,69d^2 + 32288d + 14062$ & Dummy-Kommentar7b \\
& $263,6d^2 + 37846,8d + 107171$ & Dummy-Kommentar7c \\
\multirow{3}{=}{Jens et al. (\citeyear{Jens.04.2021})} & -- & Dummy-Kommentar8a \\
& $--$ & Dummy-Kommentar8b \\
& $--$ & Dummy-Kommentar8c \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[1]$d$ is diameter in $inches$ and $l$ length in $miles$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end document
```

Maybe someone would be so nice and help me out :)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Don't use math mode to typeset whole words like "inches" or "miles" - this messes up the kerning!

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! YOu provide just fragment of code. Be so kind and extend it to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. In fragment are used some commands which we do not know where are defined.

Comment: you could use `m` not `p` for the first column (but it would look better if you used `p` for all three and top aligned the entries)

Comment: Remove all `\newline` in multirow cell. Also increase first column width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you after something like this:

[image]

- Since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document. I was guessing what is relevant in your document preamble
- In tabularx`table at least one column had to be of`X` type
- IN MWE below I replace `citeyear` with `\cite`. This should be simple to revert, when you show which package you load in preamble-
- Possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Kostenfunktionen zur Approximierung der Pipelinekosten}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\raggedright} m{0.3\textwidth} X m{0.3\textwidth} @{}}
    \toprule
Autor & Formel & Kommentar \\
    \midrule
Parker (\cite{Parker.2004}) 
    & $(924,5d^2 + 12616d + 290068) * l $\tnote{1}  & Dummy-Kommentar1 \\
    \addlinespace
Yang \& Ogden (\cite{YANG.2007}) 
    & $(1869d^2 + 300000) * l$                      & Dummy-Kommentar2 \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{3}{=}{\cite{Krieg.2012}} 
    & $(1500000d^2 + 720000d + 213900) * l$     & Dummy-Kommentar3a \\
    & $(2200000d^2 + 860000d + 247500) * l$     & Dummy-Kommentar3b \\
    & $(4000000d^2 + 600000d + 329000) * l$     & Dummy-Kommentar3c \\
    \addlinespace
ACER (\cite{AgencyoftheCooperationofEnergyRegulators.23.07.2015}), 
      ECN (\cite{Weeda.11.2017})
    & $(1021,7d^2 - 20393d + 642720) * l$       & Dummy-Kommentar4 \\
    \addlinespace
Johnson \& Ogden (\cite{Johnson.2012}) 
    & $(818,64d^2 + 14288,2d + 284530,3) * l$   & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
    \addlinespace
Andre et al.  (\cite{Andre.2013}) 
    & $2306000d^2 + 762800d + 418869$           & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
    \addlinespace
Reuß et al. (\cite{Reu.2019} 
    & $292152 * d $                             & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{4}{=}{Elgowainy \& Reddi (\cite{AmgadElgowainyandKrishnaReddi.2022})} 
    & $-9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241$     & Dummy-Kommentar5a \\
    & $-51,393d^2 + 43523d + 16171$             & Dummy-Kommentar5b \\
    & $303,13d^2 + 12908d + 123245$             & Dummy-Kommentar5c \\
    &  $-9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241$    & Dummy-Kommentar5d \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{3}{=}{d'Amore-Domenech et al. (\cite{dAmoreDomenech.2023})} 
    & $1,4d^2 + 1,5d + 1,8$             & Dummy-Kommentar7a \\
    & $-44,69d^2 + 32288d + 14062$      & Dummy-Kommentar7b \\
    & $263,6d^2 + 37846,8d + 107171$    & Dummy-Kommentar7c \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{3}{=}{Jens et al. (\cite{Jens.04.2021})} 
    & $--$                              & Dummy-Kommentar8a \\
    & $--$                              & Dummy-Kommentar8b \\
    & $--$                              & Dummy-Kommentar8c \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[1]$d$ is diameter in $inches$ and $l$ length in $miles$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** mostly off-topic ...

- By use of the `tabularray` package table code become simpler and shorter.
- I would not vertical center content of multi row cells, rather push content on the top of cells

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \SetTblrStyle{note-tag}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Kostenfunktionen zur Approximierung der Pipelinekosten},
  label = {tab:?},
note{1} = {$d$ is diameter in \textit{inches} and $l$ length in \textit{miles}},
                ]{colspec = {@{} Q[h, l] X[l, mode=math] Q[l, wd=0.25\linewidth] @{} },
                  row{1}  = {mode=text},
                  %rowsep  = 5pt
                  }
% table body
    \toprule
Autor & Formel & Kommentar \\
    \midrule
Parker (\cite{Parker.2004}) 
    & (924,5d^2 + 12616d + 290068)*l\TblrNote{1}  
                                                & Dummy-Kommentar1 \\
Yang \& Ogden (\cite{YANG.2007})
    & (1869d^2 + 300000) * l                    & Dummy-Kommentar2 \\
\SetCell[r=3]{}   \cite{Krieg.2012}
    & (1500000d^2 + 720000d + 213900) * l       & Dummy-Kommentar3a \\
    & (2200000d^2 + 860000d + 247500) * l       & Dummy-Kommentar3b \\
    & (4000000d^2 + 600000d + 329000) * l       & Dummy-Kommentar3c \\
ACER (\cite{AgencyoftheCooperationofEnergyRegulators.23.07.2015}),
      ECN (\cite{Weeda.11.2017})
    & (1021,7d^2 - 20393d + 642720) * l         & Dummy-Kommentar4 \\
Johnson \& Ogden (\cite{Johnson.2012})
    & (818,64d^2 + 14288,2d + 284530,3) * l     & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
Andre et al.  (\cite{Andre.2013})
    & 2306000d^2 + 762800d + 418869             & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
Reuß et al. (\cite{Reu.2019}
    & 292152 * d                                & Dummy-Kommentar6 \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} Elgowainy \& Reddi (\cite{AmgadElgowainyandKrishnaReddi.2022})
    & -9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241       & Dummy-Kommentar5a \\
    & -51,393d^2 + 43523d + 16171               & Dummy-Kommentar5b \\
    & 303,13d^2 + 12908d + 123245               & Dummy-Kommentar5c \\
    &  -9\text{E-13}d^2 + 4417,1d + 164241      & Dummy-Kommentar5d \\
\SetCell[r=3]{} d'Amore-Domenech et al. (\cite{dAmoreDomenech.2023})
    & 1,4d^2 + 1,5d + 1,8                       & Dummy-Kommentar7a \\
    & -44,69d^2 + 32288d + 14062                & Dummy-Kommentar7b \\
    & 263,6d^2 + 37846,8d + 107171              & Dummy-Kommentar7c \\
\SetCell[r=3]{}   Jens et al. (\cite{Jens.04.2021})
    & --                                        & Dummy-Kommentar8a \\
    & --                                        & Dummy-Kommentar8b \\
    & --                                        & Dummy-Kommentar8c \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]